# Loading templates from different server

Tags: php, html, smarty

Hey guys quite new to smarty and was wondering if i could load templates from a different web server ... i have tried

```
$smarty->template_dir = "http://www.testsite.com/templates";
```

but with no luck and have no idea what to try next any help would be greatly appricated thank you!

Comment: This may be unwise, as you would be making a call to the remote server every time you use the template. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do a

```
if(time() - file_mtime("/tmp/template_dir/tmp_template.tpl") > 86400)
file_put_contents("/tmp/template_dir/tmp_template.tpl", file_get_contents("http://www.testsite.com/templates/template.tpl"));
$smarty->template_dir = "/tmp/template_dir/";
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Smarty supports remote sources for templates, but even if it does, the problem here is that the template files will most likely be parsed as PHP on the remote server - you'd need to configure the web server on www.testsite.com to not process the template files in /templates using PHP.